# Wrong file type when sending PDF files through Whatsapp API using Postman

Tags: json, pdf, postman, whatsapp, file-type

I am trying to send a message to myself containing a PDF file stored in Onedrive through Whatsapp API but I am getting the following jpg format:

[Message in Whatsapp APP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrASJ.png)

Oddly enough, when I check Whatsapp Web the same message shows correctly:

[Message in Whatsapp Web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQbvS.png)

What am I doing wrong?

I followed the [official documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/reference/media#supported-media-types) and uploaded the media with the following values:
[values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYqwQ.png)

This returns me the id:

```
"id": "7054xxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Finally, I proceed to send the messsage using that same id:

```
{
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
    "to": "{{Recipient-Phone-Number}}",
    "type": "document",
    "document": {
        "id": "7054xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "caption": "Hello, here is today's Daily Report",
        "filename": "dailyreport.pdf"
  }
}
```

Also, I tried retrieving the media URL and got the following output:

```
{
    "url": "https://lookaside.fbsbx.com/whatsapp_business/attachments/?mid=705479771132690&ext=1670800000&hash=ATvvKq-JEv6kn0bW7kq8SXy00yD1BLX_MMbOK-xxxxxx",
    "mime_type": "image/jpeg",
    "sha256": "067e1ac9488efc068dbb1ee4a35ae30c1dec575a70a4dcd77f6cbdc396615912",
    "file_size": 1912582,
    "id": "705479771132690",
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp"
}
```

I guess "mime_type" should be "application_pdf" instead of "image/jpeg". I have no idea why it would say it is an image.

I am pretty new with this so it may be a simple mistake I am not seeing.

Thank you in advanced for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a working example to send a pdf:

```
curl -X POST 'https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/<MEDIA_ID>/media' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
-F 'file=@"documents/sales.pdf"' \
-F 'type="application/pdf"' \
-F 'messaging_product="whatsapp"'
```

You are supposed to set "type" to the media type you're posting.

See details of supported media types, and limitations, here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/reference/media#supported-media-types

Comment: Not sure what I was doing wrong, but I pasted your example and it started working. Huge thanks!

Comment: In postman I got success message but I have no message on whatsapp

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the header as content-type not just type:

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I’m still having the same issue